# How to save a jpeg image from a base64 data string with move_uploaded_file or file_put_contents?

Tags: image, php

currently i developing a mobile app that able to snap photo and save in server. I able to pass the image base64 data string to my php using AJAX. I also can decode the base64 data string to image, but cannot save in my server. Every time i run my app, the result show that i already save my image into server but when i check in my server i didn't find it. I follow the example on https://xuri.me/2014/11/18/save-a-png-image-from-a-base64-data-string-with-php.html.

Below is my php code.

```
$img = $_POST['img'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/jpg;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$img_name = uniqid();
$file_name = $img_name . '.jpeg';
$file_path = realpath("../media/rewardreceipt/");
$file_path = $file_path . "/" . $file_name ;

if(file_put_contents($file_path , $data)) {
     $arr = array('result' =>$file_name);
     echo json_encode($arr);
} else{
    $arr = array('result' =>'false');
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

Comment: What is the output? false or filename?

Comment: Do you have the rights to save the file in this folder? Think its just a right issue just chmod 777 rewardreceipt to check if it works now

Comment: Or better, check from the code with `is_writable($file_path)` and handle accordingly

Comment: first, the output is the filename second, yesterday i have check that i have the right to to save the file in the rewardreceipt folder. for double confirm, just now i check it i have no right to save the file in the rewardreceipt folder. So now what can i do?